# How to find and fetch text from a html file?

Tags: python, html, regex, python-re

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some text i want to fetch</p>
  </div>
  <RandomVueComponent>Some other text i want to fetch</RandomVueComponent>
</div>
<a href="#">Might be some text too</a>
```

I am using regex through python scripts to scan my codebase. And those scripts returns me a list of all the texts in my codebase with their file path, line... etc. So i can keep track of texts in my html files. But, i can't find a way to find all text, regardless of how much it is nested in html delimiters, and regardless of the delimiter itself. So the delimiter cannot be used as a matching key (such as `r'<p>text</p>`).

I would like to avoid using libraries as much as possible.
I have heard about Beautiful Soup, but i think it needs a matching key (such as the html tag).

What did i try ? I tried some sketchy regex that didn't work obviously.

Comment: [HTML and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is an unholy alliance. Beautifulsoup should be able to manage what you want to do. Give it a try.

Comment: Have you tried traversing the text?  Determine which tags can contain content, or better, which cannot, and simply _substring_ the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
(?<=\>)[A-Za-z0-9 ]+
```

Comment: This excludes all letters outside the ASCII range and I'm very mispleased when someone takes "Motörhead" away from me. And this is just one of the many flaws of this approach. Simply replace the text in the p-element in the question with "Don't forget this".